# Access query: Update with a DSum in SET

Tags: sql, ms-access

I get the error "**Operation must use an updateable query**" when I try to run this SQL code:

```
UPDATE Progetti 
SET Progetti.Eroso = (SELECT sum(Fatture.Fattura) FROM Fatture WHERE Fatture.[Codice Progetto] = Progetti.[Codice Progetto]);
```

Consider that all the tables, fields and relationships involved exist and are correctly set. The issue (according to me) is that `SELECT` cannot be inside `SET`. Is it correct?

So what can be a right solution?

The result must be: for each `Progetti.[Codice Progetto]` put in the field `Progetti.Eroso` the sum only of `Fatture.Fattura` related to `Progetti.[Codice Progetto]`.

An alternative can be:

```
UPDATE Progetti AS a 
SET a.Eroso = DSum("Fattura", "Fatture", "[Codice Progetto]=" & a.[Codice Progetto]);
```

But I get this warning:

[image]

**EDIT**

I have tried the solution of ***@user4321***:

```
UPDATE Progetti 
SET Progetti.Eroso = Fatture2.FatturaSum 
FROM Progetti
Inner Join (SELECT sum(Fatture.Fattura) as FatturaSum
             FROM Fatture) as Fatture2  
ON Fatture2.[Codice Progetto] = Progetti.[Codice Progetto];
```

Maybe I have found why it does not work: `Fatture.[Codice Progetto]` is probably linked to `Progetti.[ID Progetto]` (that is different from `Progetti.[ID Progetto]`). The field is set in this way:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

hope this works for you

```
UPDATE Progetti 
SET Progetti.Eroso = Fatture2.FatturaSum 
FROM Progetti
Inner Join (SELECT sum(Fatture.Fattura) as FatturaSum
             FROM Fatture) as Fatture2  
ON Fatture2.[Codice Progetto] = Progetti.[Codice Progetto];
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. I get this error: **Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'sum(Fatture.Fattura FROM Fatture'**

Comment: thanks but still not working. Always syntax error. It seems to be not easy :')

Comment: Try once now and let me know if you still see an error. please paste the error here.

Comment: maybe I have found why it does not work. I have updated the question. Tell me if it is not clear.